# check_email_exists.php solution?

Tags: php

I am trying to check email which is actually existed or not via php script and I found a solution that can really solve it.

I came across from this article https://gist.github.com/sureshdsk/9c599d757e90b0215e55 .

Please check complete code there, and let me show only my problem pane.

```
  //(Lower-most lines of the project)
  $email="asadbksdhskhdksjfhk@gmail.com";  //email to test
  $check =verifyEmail($email, 'youremail@gmail.com'); //your email is just used for smtp requests
  if($check=="valid"){
     echo "success";
  }else{  
     echo "fail";  
  }
```

Everything is OK by changing target email and host email, it shows "success". 
But I want this php script to be processed by sending data and don't want it to be static.
So I changed ..

```
   $email="asadbksdhskhdksjfhk@gmail.com";  //email to test
```

to

```
   $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
```

and try sending email as data like this .

```
  http://www.samplesample.com/check_email_exists.php?email="test@gmail.com"
```

But not working as the other scripts in my hosting do. By echoing email, it shows blank(null).
Please kindly suggest for my problem. Thank you for reading and thinking about it.I am new to web programming,php .

Comment: You want to validate a email??

Comment: Remove the quotes from the query string `http://www.samplesample.com/check_email_exists.php?email=test@gmail.com`

Comment: yes, to validate email . to know Fake or Real .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` to validate email in php.
Try this code,

```
//http://www.samplesample.com/check_email_exists.php?email=test@gmail.com

$email=$_REQUEST['email'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
     echo("$email is a valid email address");
} else {
     echo("$email is not a valid email address");
}
```

Comment: Checking ... Thanks for answering .

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for code . It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plug-in class [recommended via another answer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6650-PHP-Check-if-an-e-mail-is-valid-using-SMTP.html) which checks if the Email Address is valid using SMTP, that should free up all the complicated parts of developing the logic to test it.

Comment: Checking ... Thanks for answering .

Comment: No problem at all! Actually I figured that what Niranjan posted was what you wanted but I wasn't sure if it would check if the email actually existed or not..

Comment: I am absolutely sure for right marked answer. I am started using it in my app. :)